# How to access personal ubuntu computer remotely

Tags: 14.04, remote-access, remote-login

Currently I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I want the steps to access my personal computer remotely without using team viewer. Could you please help me for the same.
Is it possible to access my computer remotely when host is offline ?

Thanks,
Rohan

Comment: Use Remmina remote Desktop Client for remotely access.

Comment: Can you provide any more info? Are both computers running Linux? Do you want to see the GUI of the other computer in the same way that Remote Desktop or Team Viewer does, or do you just want to access it through a shell?

Comment: I want to access my ubuntu computer on windows. Yes I want access gui also.

Comment: @Benjamin R I want to access my ubuntu computer on windows. Yes I want access gui also.

Comment: host is offline? what do you mean by host is offline?

Comment: I mean if computer which I want offline, is it necessary to be in network or is it possible to access it when it is shutdown ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For remote access to PC I propose ssh. Secure shell crypt traffic, also you can with option  -X from client start, on client, app from server.

Detailed manual have on link [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Configuring).

If you access ubuntu from win you can use [putty](http://www.putty.org/).

Answer (score 0):

[There is no standard way to login remotely to Ubuntu with GUI.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1247574)
I don't know of any good non-standard ways as well.

You cannot connect to an offline host because it is not online, obviously. However, if it's just turned off, it may be possible to setup the wake up on LAN/WAN feature on your network card. Consult manual for your BIOS for the details. You should be able to send remotely a special packet to wake up your computer.